# ReactJS examples fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the following example from ReactJS tutorial:

```
const Button = function() {
   return {<button>Go</button>;
   };

};
ReactDOM.render(<Button/>, mountNode);
```

I tried it both in a file and int Javascript REPL and getting the same error:

```
  SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (4:9)
  2 | 
  3 | const Button = function() {
> 4 |   return {<button>Go</button>;
    |           ^
  5 |   };
  6 | 
  7 | };
```

Cannot figure out what is wrong - it seems to work fine in the same setting in the tutorial video.

Comment: That's JSX, not JavaScript. Are you sure you're running it correctly?

Comment: You need a [transpiler](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/) to turn JSX into JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change brackets `return {<button>Go</button>;};` to `return(<button>Go</button>);`

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I did not catch that

Answer (score 0):

You component is a `function` component and you don't wrap the returned Elements within `{}`. If you do it means you are returning an `object`

```js
const Button = function() {
   return <button>Go</button>;

};
const mountNode= document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<Button/>, mountNode);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```